# Strange exception, JDK 6.0.29 bug?

Tags: java, exception

Was experimenting with interface inheritance and found this:

```
interface String{}
interface Object{}
interface Exception{}
interface Integer extends String, Object, Exception{}

public class Test implements Integer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

it's compiling, but throws `"main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main` at runtime?

Comment: How are you executing it? Are you in the same directory as `Test.class`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because main method signature should be:

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
```

if you write

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
```

it gets an array of your String interfaces, so the signature is different

Comment: Well the thing is, even if i comment out String interface the problem remains

Comment: you don't need to comment your String interface; just type your main method as i did above (with explicit java.lang.String) and it will compile and run successfully

Comment: however, as duffymo suggests, this sample does not generate any useful knowledge i can see; have a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613130/multiple-interfaces-extending-in-java to learn a possible use of interface inheritance

Answer (score 3):

If you commend out your inadvisable `String` interface, the `Test` class tries to extend `java.lang.String`, which is a final class.  You *can't* extend it.  And asking an interface like your Integer to extend a *class* instead of another *interface* should draw a compiler error.

I see nothing educational about this experiment.  None of it should ever find its way into real code.